# Superposition of two electromagnetic waves

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations, superposition, linear-systems

If an electromagnetic wave in isolation with vector potential $A^1_{\alpha}$ satisfies the wave equation $\Box A^1_{\alpha}=0$, how do we construct the total electromagnetic wave that results from superposing such electromagnetic waves with individual vector potentials $A^1_{\alpha},A^2_{\alpha}$. Is the total solution then simply $A_{\alpha}=A^1_{\alpha}+A^2_{\alpha}$ and satisfies $\Box A_{\alpha}=0$? Or is the total solution more complicated than that and I am mistaken in simply calculating the solution as the sum of its individual solutions?

The aim of this question is to consider a light pulse with vector potential $A^1_{\alpha}$ brought close to another light pulse with vector potential $A^2_{\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Maxwell equations are linear, the sum of two solutions is a solution. Hence, you are correct in stating that the superposition of two solutions is simply their sum.

This can be used to simplify a lot of problems. For example, if you have a problem with static charge and current density, you can separately treat the effects due to the charge density (Electrostatics) and due to the current density (Magnetostatics) and then add both solutions together.